# Oil-water interface simulation using Gromacs

Tags: computational-physics, simulations, physical-chemistry, surface-tension, molecular-dynamics

I would like to perform a decane/water(tip4p) interface simulation using GROMACS to analyse the fluctuation of the interface over a long period of time (50ps - 1ns).

Though I have a rough idea on how to perform it, I still am unsure about how to create a initial configuration which looks like the figure give below (A.R. Buuren, Ph.D. Thesis, University of Groningen, 1995). [image]

Also once I start my production run I would like to know, how to obtain the height fluctuations of the interface as a function of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way would be to simulate bulk water and bulk decane, separately, to generate two relaxed configurations for each phase.

You will want them to both be the same pressure but to have the same cell dimensions in the x and y plane, so you should perform NPT but only allowing the cells to relax in the z-direction.

Then write a script to stick the two relaxed configurations together, side-by-side, into a single cell. You will need to reverse any breaking apart of the individual molecules by the periodic boundary conditions first though.

Then relax the merged simulation cell under NPT (this time allowing all three cell vectors to relax).

> how to obtain the height fluctuations of the interface as a function of time

One possible idea: construct a histogram along the z-dimension where, for each decane you add (+1), and for each water molecule you minus (-1). Then  your histogram will cross zero in two places - these define the boundary where the two phases meet.